# how to close a modal window using a button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a modal window but I want to set up a close function so that when the user clicks on the "button", it will close the modal window. Does anyone know how this can be achieved?

I have a link to the application so you can view it [here](http://helios.hud.ac.uk/u0867587/Mobile_app/QandATable2.php)

Below is the javascript code where it shows the function of opening the modal window and the setup function of where I want to place the code to close the modal window:

```
function plusbutton() {
    $(".previouslink").modal(); 
    return false;
}
function closewindow() {    
    return false;
}
```

Below is the form code where user clicks on the plus button and it displays the content within the "previouslink" div tag:

```
<form id="QandA" action="imageupload.php" method="post">
    <h1>CREATING QUESTIONS AND ANSWERS</h1>
    <table id="plus" align="center">
        <tr>
            <th><a onclick="return plusbutton();">
<image src="Images/plussign.jpg" width="30" height="30" alt="Look Up Previous Question" class="plusimage"/>
            </a><span id="plussignmsg">(Click Plus Sign to look <br />
            up Previous Questions)</span> </th>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <div class="previouslink">
        <h1>PREVIOUS QUESTIONS</h1>
        <button type="button" id="close" onclick="return closewindow();">Close
        </button></div>
</form>
```

Comment: It's not tagged as jQuery, yet it's jQuery code. Why didn't you just use the jQuery dialog?

Comment: There is no `<image>` tag. Use `<img>`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your Live-Example shows me, that you seem to be using [SimpleModal](http://www.ericmmartin.com/projects/simplemodal/)

From the documentation:

> **CLOSING THE DIALOG**
>
> SimpleModal will automatically bind the close
>   function (using the onclick event) to any element inside the dialog
>   with the `simplemodal-close` class. In addition, you can
>   programmatically close the currently opened dialog by calling
>   `$.modal.close();`

Means: In your `closeWindow()`-Function, you could simply enter the line:

```
$.modal.close();
```

and be done.

Answer (score 0):

I've used this [jQuery reveal modal plugin](http://www.zurb.com/playground/reveal-modal-plugin) on several sites and it has worked great for me.

Alternatively, you should check out [jQuery Impromptu](http://trentrichardson.com/Impromptu/). I love the tour feature myself, but the modals are more likely what you are trying to accomplish.

The code from both examples will probably lead you to what you are specifically looking for :)